# Проблема с подключеним cURL к проекту

Tags: curl, c++

Очередной мой ступок в изучении с++. Прошу помочь мне с сложившейся проблемой. 
Я создал пустой VC++ проект. Пытаюсь подключить к нему библиотеку cUrl. Скачал libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc с офф сайта. Прописал пути к хедерам, прописал путь к lib файлу и добавил в список lib. Вроде все хорошо, пытаюсь скомпилировать, компилируется, но при запуске крешить с

**"Ошибка при запуске приложения(0хс0150002). Для выхода из приложения нажмите копку ОК"**.

По гуглив наткнулся на решение добавить несколько бибилиотек в проект, таких как: libeay32.dll, openldap.dll, ssleay32.dll и libsasl.dll. Куда только я не пытался их разместить, но проблему это не решило. Если у кого возникали такие проблемы прошу поделиться с ее решением.

Comment: Проблема решилась, заменой dll debug версии  на release.

Comment: у вас возникали ошибки после этого?

Comment: Нет все работало хорошо!